# Laravel Many to Many name turned around

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using a many to many structure in my project but when I try to add something to it, Laravel turns the names around.

My table is called **user_event** ( i named it like that in my migration )
Laravel tries to add the data to **event_user**

Here's my code

```
public function subscribe($event)
{
    \Auth::user()->events()->save(Event::find($event));
}
```

And this is the error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'manytomany.event_user' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `event_user`
>   (`event_id`, `user_id`) values (3, 1))

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the table on event model - `protected $table = 'user_event';`

It is happening because laravel tries to get table with names in alphabetical order by default. So it will look for `event_user` not 'user_event'.

Where you defined the relation do this -

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Event', 'user_event');
```

Comment: Hm, But the Event is a model itself, I also have an event table.. so that would not help right?

Comment: it will use `pivot` table for this. set the pivot table then.

Comment: Thank you sgt. The ('Event', 'user_event'); is working. without the protected $table = 'user_event';